# Сохранение Bitmap при смене ориентации

Tags: android, bitmap

Есть некоторый `Bitmap`, который в процессе работы устанавливается в `ImageView` и устройство с периодическим изменением ориентации экрана.
Необходимо, чтобы после смены ориентации `Bitmap` оставался в своем `ImageView`.

---

В документации сказано использовать `LruCache`. Пробую:

**Инициализирую `LruCache<String, Bitmap>` в `onCreate()`** и переопределяю его метод `sizeOf()` (это же, кстати, можно не делать, если важно количество элементов, а не их вес?):

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        shared = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(1) { // хранить будем всего 1 bitmap
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                return 1;
            }
    };
```

**Добавляю 2 метода на добавление и чтение `Bitmap` из кеша**

```
    private final String KEY_MAIN_IMAGE = "MAIN_IMAGE";
    private void addBitmapToCache(Bitmap bitmap) {
        cache.put(KEY_MAIN_IMAGE, bitmap);
    }


    private Bitmap getBitmapFromCache() {
        return cache.get(KEY_MAIN_IMAGE);
    }
```

**И переопределяю сохранение и загрузку данных**

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    addBitmapToCache(bitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache();
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

И все это дело благополучно не работает. Подскажите где я ошибся или как правильно работать с `LruCache`?

Comment: Где Вам предложили использовать LruCache при смене ориентации? Можно ссылку?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei а есть другие, более простые в реализации способы?
прочитал тут: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#config-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putParcelable("lastImg", bitmap);
}
```

....

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
super.onCreate(savedState);
if (savedState != null) bitmap = savedState.getParcelable("lastImg");
}
```

Comment: Очень странно. Когда я так делал, он мне говорил, что `Bitmap` не есть `Parcelable`. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы не реализовали часть из доки http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#config-changes

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    RetainFragment retainFragment =
            RetainFragment.findOrCreateRetainFragment(getFragmentManager());
    mMemoryCache = retainFragment.mRetainedCache;
    if (mMemoryCache == null) {
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            ... // Initialize cache here as usual
        }
        retainFragment.mRetainedCache = mMemoryCache;
    }
    ...
}

class RetainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "RetainFragment";
    public LruCache<String, Bitmap> mRetainedCache;

    public RetainFragment() {}

    public static RetainFragment findOrCreateRetainFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
        RetainFragment fragment = (RetainFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new RetainFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG).commit();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

И у вас при пересоздании благополучно погибает кэш, так как на него не остается ссылок.